# Как организовать быстрый поиск при отсутствии точных значений?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив значений

```
int[] limit = new int[] {350 , 570, 680, 720, 1200};
```

Есть переменная

```
int cnt
```

которая увеличивается, но не с равным шагом, например  5,6,8,12,15,20,30,32 и т.д.

Задача: отловить моменты, когда переменная cnt становится больше одного из значений массива и в эти моменты вывести логи ("достигло первого значения", "достигло второго" и т.д.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вообще не понимаю в чем ваша проблема. Особенно учитывая что массив отсортированный. Есвли он будет не отсортирвоанный - то нужно отсортирвоать (можно через `Arrays.sort`).

А дальше все примтивно:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < limit.size()) {
    if (limit[index] < getCnt()) { // или как там ваше значение cnt получается, я не знаю. вы этого не описали
         sout("Value #" + index + " reached");
         index++;
    }
}
```

Можно и перевернуть:

```
int index = 0;
for (int cnt = 0; magic(); cnt = magicGenerator()) { // Опять же, вы не описали как формируется ваш cnt
    if (limit[index] < cnt) {
         sout("Value #" + index + " reached");
         index++;
    }
}
```

*Добавлено:*

Извиняюсь, упустил вариант, когда одним увеличением `cnt` может быть достигнуто несолько точек из `limit`

```
int index = 0;
for (int cnt = 0; magic(); cnt = magicGenerator()) {
    while (limit[index] < cnt) {
         sout("Value #" + index + " reached");
         index++;
    }
}
```

А еще массив может закончится раньше:

```
int index = 0;
for (int cnt = 0; magic(); cnt = magicGenerator()) {
    if (index >= limit.size()) {
         return;
    }
    while (limit[index] < cnt) {
         sout("Value #" + index + " reached");
         index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно элементарно! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, массив лучше отсортировать.
Далее, при итерации переменной, проверять первый элемент массива 
+- допустимая погрешность.
Затем увеличить индекс массива и проверять его.
Поиск тут не требуется.